# Replacing Letters with Numbers in sequence in an excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm wanting to update a column based on another that has drill holes listed in sequence, the update needs to replace a character within the sequence, such that A = 0, B = 1, C = 2 etc... Is there a way to do this without writing a really big IF/Then type formula?

I've tried the replace formula, but I've only managed to update one letter at a time..

In the example below; The Hole_ID_2 (column R) is the desired output using the Hole_ID (Column P) data.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as all IDs to replace are of the same structure (10 characters in length and the letter to replace at position 8), one could get the `ANSI` code of the letter using `CODE` and calculate that code to the appropriate number then.

That would avoid many nested `SUBSTITUTE` functions.

Your Example:

[image]

Formula in `R3` downwards:

```
=LEFT(P3,7)&CODE(MID(P3,8,1))-65&RIGHT(P3,2)
```

Comment: Thanks Axel, that is what I was after. Cheers

Comment: And once the right hand number goes to 3 digits ie 99 + 2 ... or the left hand side changes...

Comment: @Solar Mike: I have clearly stated: "As long as all IDs to replace are of the same structure (10 characters in length and the letter to replace at position 8)".

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the substitute() function?

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A3,"a",1),"b",2),"c",3)
```

assuming your data starts in cell A3.

[image]